# how to squish text together in css?

Tags: html, css, text

I was **wondering** how to squish my text together? So it wasn't pushing outside of the page? Any suggestions?

---

**Problem:**

[image: Issue]

---

**Code:**

```css
.Subheading{
    text-align:center;
    font-family: 'Mukta', sans-serif;
    margin-top:70px;
    margin-left:-500px;
    font-size:30px;
}
```

```html
<p class="Subheading">Thanks for you the family of the random of the screen of the something yes ok no understood no what nevermind.</p>
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Remove this `margin-left:-500px;`

Comment: I want it to be like that, on the left side of the screen, but you see, I was the text to keep going downwards, not sidewards, can I do that?

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the **shortest code** necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself** preferably in a [**Stack Snippet**](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/).  See [**How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/reprex). We need to see the exact problem

Answer (score -1):

You can add padding of 500px to cancel out the margin of `-500px`.
Give more details if this does not work for you.

```css
.Subheading{
    text-align:center;
    font-family: 'Mukta', sans-serif;
    margin-top:70px;
    margin-left:-500px;
    padding-left:500px;
    font-size:30px;
    text-align: left;
}
```

```html
<p class="Subheading">Thanks for you the family of the random of the screen of the something yes ok no understood no what nevermind.</p>
```

Comment: That is kinda what I want, you see when I press run snippet, it goes downwards, but I want that exact same downwards, but like bunched together, but like on the left of the screen. (You see it alot in famous websites like amazon, and etc.)

Comment: do you mean left aligned? see now.

Comment: in a way, yes, so like I want that kind of bunched up text, but just on the left of the screen. 

(I sadly don't know the term for this).